# How to convert a string value to date

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a form where an admin selects a date from 3 drop downs 
and marks an employee as present or absent.

My attendance table has the following columns:

- emp_id : int
- date : date
- status : varchar

I have 3 drop downs in an html form, one each for YYYY, MM and DD selection. I would like to capture these values as date and insert it into a date column in a table. How can I do that? I have tried searching for functions on the internet 
but I haven't able to effectively use any one of them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried. You said you have searched and no solutions worked. But the actual solution is pretty simple, and we could help if you elaborate your question better.

Comment: Have you tried using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?  It's flexible at detecting dates from a variety of string formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date will be inserted into MySQL, all these formatting with `sprintf()` or `strtotime()` is totally unnecessary.

MySQL expects [date and time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) in the following formats for the date data type:

> • As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed”
>   syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the
>   delimiter between date parts. For example, '2012-12-31', '2012/12/31',
>   '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31' are equivalent.
>
> • As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYMMDD'
>   format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example,
>   '20070523' and '070523' are interpreted as '2007-05-23', but '071332'
>   is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes
>   '0000-00-00'.
>
> • As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the
>   number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905 and 830905 are
>   interpreted as '1983-09-05'.

Just produce one of the formats accepted by MySQL using simple string concatenation from the form input in php and then use this data as parameter in the insert sql statement.

Comment: it works perfect .. I concatenated the yyyy, mm , and dd selections and inserted the value into the date column in the table .
by far your solution has been the most effective and the simplest one ..you rock!!

Comment: If the above answer helped you to resolve your issue, then pls mark it as accepted to let other viewers know that the question has already been answered!

Answer (score 1):

Have you *really* searched for possible solutions? There's plenty of them: `DateTime`, `DateTime::createFromFormat`, or if you prefer to keep things procedural: `date_create` and `date_create_from_format` respectively will both do the same thing:

```
$date = new DateTime(
    sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $year, $month, $day)
);
echo $date->format('U');//get unix timestamp
```

Read [`DateTime` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and related pages for details.

If all you're after is the timestamp, as Cam suggested [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is probably your best bet:

```
$timestamp = strtotime(
    sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $year, $month, $day)
);
```

Depending on the field type, you'll either want a timestamp, or some formatted string, in which case `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` with or without the `H:i:s` bit are the most likely candidates

Comment: MySQL, like a lot of SQL systems, prefers [ISO-8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The slashes are American style and not universal. Given the raw values are expressed in the form there's really no reason to parse these and then spit them back out again, just use `sprintf` to compose.

Comment: @tadman: The slashes weren't used as the value to insert (at the end, I actually suggest `Y-m-d H:i:s` as the most likely format to use for inserting). I used the slashes as a possible format to _parse_ the date. OP said the date value is coming from 3 different input fields, so he'll probably want to bring them together. I know, with 100% certainty that the `Y/m/d` format is understood and predictable when used with `DateTime`, I did not suggest to use that format for (My)SQL

Comment: Three independent fields sounds to me like three separate variables coming in, so to smash them together with slashes seems like a giant waste of time *unless* you're doing some kind of date validation. I don't see that here, so employing DateTime is extraneous. Why not skip to the part where you do `sprintf('%4d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day)`?

Comment: @tadman: Agreed, if there's no validation at all, there's no point in using `DateTime` or anything. In case OP wants to validate whether or not the given date falls within a range, or is > today, then `DateTime` & co do make sense